# Maya - Create ikHandle for each joints selected with Python

Tags: python, maya

I'm an animation student that's learning rigging and python to automate some parts. I have a series of joints where I want to create a ikHandle from the parent and the child.

Here's an example of the hierarchy

- group

  - joint1

    - joint2
  - joint3

    - joint4

I'm able to create a ikHandle from joint1 and joint2 by selecting joint1 and using the code below.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(sl=True, dag=True)

cmds.ikHandle (sj=selection[0], ee=selection[1])
```

The problem is I'm unsure on how I would find a child of every selected joint and create an ikHandle to its parent.

Thank you in advance and I apologise if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work it out an hour after I posted the question. I chucked it in a for loop and used listRelatives to find the child

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)

for each in selection:
    child = mc.listRelatives( each , c = True ) [0]
    cmds.ikHandle (sj=each, ee=child)
```